# Where should I install Filebeat if I want to see on Kibana logs from azure function?

Tags: azure, logging, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have some Azure Functions deployed. Now I want to send logs data to Elastic to be able to manage these logs in Kibana. For that I should use Filebeat.

The first instruction I receive there is "**install Filebeat on each system you want to monitor**", so I am not getting where should I install the Filebeat. The system I want to monitor are these functions that are deployed in Azure. There is something I am not understanding. I someone can help me, I will appreciatte it!

The system I want to monitor are these functions that are already deployed in Azure, I should install Filbeat in the Azure portal? That makes no sense.

I understand that the Filebeat process will be hearing an event-hub where I will send my logs, to send that logs to the elastic cloud. But I don't understand where I should install this Filebeat process.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we need to create a Virtual Machine in Azure with Windows as OS, and we installed the Filebeat there.
At end is a service (a windows service in our case) that is hearing the event hub.